# Django: Common/Reusable ModelAdmin Class

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have some functions like:

```
has_delete_permission, 
has_add_permission, 
get_actions, 
formfield_for_foreignkey
get_queryset
```

Etc are the built-in ModelAdmin functions which I am using in almost all the ModelsAdmin's in my project.

How to create a common/reusable class which include these functions and reuse in the other ModelAdmin classes?

How to pass the reference of the Model or the ModelAdmin class to the common class?

What should be the file structure to be maintained, in case this has to be used for many apps in a project.

Some direction will be great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using Python's class's [multiple inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) to achieve this. It would look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Banana


class MyAdminMixin:
    def has_delete_permission(self, obj):
        # Your code goes here

    def has_add_permission(self, obj):
        # Your code goes here


class BananaModelAdmin(MyAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Now your admin has access to the methods in MyAdminMixin
    model = Banana
```

For some more information on using mixins with class-based views, take a look at the [Django docs on the subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/mixins/). Hope this helps!